# D3.JS: implementing Force-Directed Graph for my tag data structure

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to use the [Force-Directed Graph](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045#miserables.json) in my application.
But I'm really stuck in implementing it with my tags data.

My tag data structure is like:

```
for each Tag{
"name":<The name of the tags>
"friends":<a list of names of other tags that this tag need to be connected with>
}
```

I noticed in the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045#miserables.json) links has indexes for source and target nodes.
But I don't have this with my dynamic data.

Any idea?

BTW, I'm using AngularJS with D3 and data is in Angular.

Thanks!!

Comment: The links need to be a list of objects with source and target properties, each referencing a node. The node can be specified either by index, or by reference to the node object. You'll need to replace the names with one of those.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I think I could use my data to create all of the nodes first, but I don't know how to get the references of the nodes I create. I would like to store them(reference to those nodes) into a set then I could search the set and find the nodes in a friends list and make links for them. Do you know how to create nodes and also store them into a set in D3? Thanks!

Comment: It might be easier to replace the names in the list of friends with their index in the list of nodes.

Comment: After creating nodes, how could I get their corresponding index? And since I'm going to get these data directly from database, so I'm not able to change them. I could create another variable, like hash table and use it to look up index of nodes according to a name of a tag. My biggest concern for now is I'm not sure if I could get the index of a node I just created in D3. I don't see any examples do that. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: This is the index in your data structure. If your first element is "foo", any occurrence of "foo" in the list of friends should be replaced with 0.

Comment: Thanks! I think I could use angularJS to get the index. I have two more question though.1)In the example,seems we need to pass all the links and nodes to force ( force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();) but in my data structure, I don't have links. How could I get around this?(I don't want to construct links in the background since it may take some time) 2)Is there any build-in D3 function/mechanism to restrict two nodes could only have 1 or zero link? Thank you!

Comment: You need separate node and link data structures. There's nothing in D3 that allows you to restrict the number of links.

Answer (score 0):

My final approach is using angular directive. In the functions for the directive, I first generates links object then do other d3 stuff. This [article](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html) is very helpful! My [unperfected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719366/angularjs-and-d3-angular-directive-for-d3-load-multiple-times) code is [here](https://github.com/Sihui/MarkIt/blob/master/static/ng-app.js).